# Cannot login to phpMyAdmin error #1862 - Your password has expired

Tags: mysql, authentication, phpmyadmin

I installed MySQL, PHP, and phpMyAdmin following [this tutorial](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-phpmyadmin-working-osx-10-10-yosemite/). Everything works well, i.e., I can start and connect to MySQL through the command line without any error, but the problem is when I try to login to phpMyAdmin, I receive this error:

> #1862 - Your password has expired. To log in you must change it using a
> client that supports expired passwords.

It might worth saying that my current MySQL password is not the temporary one that I received when I installed MySQL, but I changed it later (before installing phpMyAdmin), and now trying to login to phpMyAdmin with this new (current) password shows me the above error.

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok, finally I did not understand what was the reason for this issue, but the following solution  worked for me:

1. Enter this in terminal (in /usr/local/mysql/bin/) `mysqladmin -u root -p password`
2. Enter your password
3. Enter New password
4. Done! I could then login from phpmyadmin too!

Hope it help others who have similar problem,

Comment: but when i try to do this, i get `mysqladmin: unable to change password; error: 'Column count of mysql.user is wrong. Expected 45, found 46. The table is probably corrupted'` can you suggest any solution please.

Answer (score 3):

### MySQL password has expired

From MySQL 5.7.4 the default value for `default_password_lifetime` is 360 (a year). If you make no changes to this variable or individual user accounts, all user passwords expire after 360 days (so you get: "Your password has expired. To log in you must change it using a client that supports expired passwords").

To prevent automatic password expiry, log in as root (`mysql -u root -p`):

For *clients that automatically connect to the server* (e.g. from scripts.) change the password expiration settings:

`ALTER USER 'script'@'localhost' PASSWORD EXPIRE NEVER;`

*or* you can disable auto-password-expiry for *all users*:

`SET GLOBAL default_password_lifetime = 0;`

#### Links I used to understand and fix this

[MySQL: Password Expiration and Sandbox Mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/password-expiration-sandbox-mode.html)
[MySQL: Password Expiration Policy](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/password-expiration-policy.html)
[Password expiration policy in MySQL Server 5.7](http://mysqlblog.fivefarmers.com/2014/03/31/password-expiration-policy-in-mysql-server-5-7/)