# phpMyAdmin cannot log into MySQL Server

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I downloaded and installed apache2.4+php7, and set phpmyadmin in C:/Program Files/tomcat/webapps/ROOT. I also set Documentroot of apache to C:/Program Files/tomcat/webapps/ROOT. I can log into MySQL in cmd correctly, my user id is root, password is root. apache2.4 is running.

When I type "http://localhost/phpmyadmin", I can get into the login page below[image]

I edited config.default.php in C:/Program Files/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/phpmyadmin/libraries, here are some settings I edited:

```
$cfg['PmaAbsoluteUri'] = 'http://localhost/phpmyadmin/';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost'; 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'root';
$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'zh';
```

Howerver, when I type name and password into it, it shows
[image]
It says

> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1862): Unknown error 1862

I totally don't know how to solve it, can someone help me?

Comment: Error 1862 seems to turn up that your password is expired. Why it says 'unknown' ...

Comment: It's a error for password expired. Simply reset your password.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cannot login to phpmyadmin error #1862 - Your password has expired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35995792/cannot-login-to-phpmyadmin-error-1862-your-password-has-expired)

Comment: @IncredibleHat I just installed apache, php and mysql today, I searched in Google, but all about password is expired, totally no idea.

Comment: Try just resetting the password as Bhavin mentioned. It may still work, as who knows, maybe during install it set a 1 minute password or something. Worth a try at least to rule it out.

Comment: @IncredibleHat  Thank you very much! It can be solve by the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Password is too simple? Try changing MySQL password to something a little longer and different than what you have.

Comment: It seems @IncredibleHat is right, I changed password to 123 again and still can log in, but still thank you for helping me.